# Why does this program have no output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am attempting to create a lock to prevent both threads from printing at the same time. However the script runs and completes without error but without any output. How do I make the program print an output.

I have tried renaming the lock and using the multithreading library instead of the treading library but I got even more errors using the multithreading library. I have tried setting a lock on print directly, however that causes errors with using print at all.

```
import threading

lo = threading.Lock()

class Hello(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for a in range(500):
            global lo
            with lo:
                print("Hello")

class Hi(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for b in range(500):
            global lo
            with lo:
                print("Hi")

t1=threading.Thread(target=Hello)
t2=threading.Thread(target=Hi)

t1.run()
t2.run()
```

I am expecting the strings "Hello" and "Hi" to print on separate lines, however the output is entirely missing.

Comment: Call `start()` on each thread. You may want to consider calling `join()` on each as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import threading

lo = threading.Lock()

def Hello(self):
    for a in range(500):
        global lo
        with lo:
            print("Hello")

def Hi(self):
    for b in range(500):
        global lo
        with lo:
            print("Hi")

t1=threading.Thread(target=Hello)
t2=threading.Thread(target=Hi)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Check the docs for the `threading` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: This answer is saying use `start()` instead of `run()`.